# Authenticate Using Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a app that uses azure authentication that uses the logged in credentials from visual studio to validate automatically when you use the app.I want to switch over to VS Code but how can i achieve the same results?

I tried adding it to azure account extension.

Comment: What is the framework and version of your WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

same like visual studio in your `javascript` file add `javascript` code for login which is use it.

for example if in visual studio you are login with a dialog then same in vs code create a `login.html` file.

in url add your client id and your redirect_uri.

```js
let dialog;
function login() {
    let url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=Add your client id here without any space &response_type=token&redirect_uri= your redirect_uri &scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
    //let a = "https://localhost:44397/Redirect.html";

    // mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
    // Declare dialog as global for use in later functions.
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 30, width: 20 },
        function (asyncResult) {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        }
    );
}
function processMessage(arg) {
    dialog.close();
    let messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    console.log("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
  //  window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
}
```

in your dialog file use this code to get Access Token

```js
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

        var address_Link = window.location.href;
        console.log(address_Link)
        var address_arr = address_Link.split("=");
        var address_Token = address_arr[1];
        var Id_Token = address_Token.split("&");
        var access_token = Id_Token[0];
        console.log(Id_Token)

        Office.onReady(function (appInfo) {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(access_token));

</script>
```